# Is it possible to write unit tests with Angular scenario?

Tags: javascript, testing

I am writing unit tests on javascript with Jasmine. But is there a way to write them with Angular scenario? I know we can write e2e tests with Angular scenario.What about unit tests?

Answer (score 0):

There is.

Never did this exactly in javascript, but there's an example for both unit and e2e in coffeescript (~javascript), maybe you're interested

https://github.com/PavelVanecek/angular-coffee-seed/tree/master/test